# There was a problem using the SLD REST Service (' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command)

Tags: sld, extensions, geoserver-sld-service

I've been learning how to use SLD REST Service in Geoserver (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/sldservice/index.html)
which has some problems Some commands cannot be run, for example:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XGET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/sldservice/states/classify.xml?attribute=PERSONS&method=quantile&intervals=3
```

> 'method' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> 'intervals' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file

.

[image]

How should I solve this problem?

(newbie just learning to use Geoserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote or escape the `&` in your URL as the shell is interpreting them as you wanting to run the command in the background and as there is not a program called `intervals` or `method` on your path it gives you an error.

Try instead:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XGET "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/sldservice/states/classify.xml?attribute=PERSONS&method=quantile&intervals=3"
```